# Trying to exclude a set of vm from a list in Input parameters

Tags: azure, powershell

I am trying to stop a set of vm's  and the first batch needs to include all vm's excluding ones containing
`'*DB*','*web*'` in their names and later moving to the next batch for stopping vm containing `'*DB*','*web*'`.Whats the input i should add to exclude those vm's in the first batch .

In here  `$vname=@('*','*DB*','*web*')`

```
if($action -eq "stop"){

           Write-Host "You have choosen to Stop VM's in '$bubbleName' ResourceGroup"

           $vname=@('*','*DB*','*web*')
           $i=0
           do{
           Write-Host "Stopping VM with "$vname[$i]
           $vmList = Get-AzVM -ResourceGroupName $bubbleName -Name $vname[$i]

           foreach($vlist in $vmList){
    
               

                $params = @($vlist.Name,$vlist.ResourceGroupName)
                $job = Start-Job -ScriptBlock {
                param($ComputerName,$serviceName)
                Stop-AzVM -Name $ComputerName -ResourceGroupName $serviceName -Force
                } -ArgumentList $params 
                $jobs = $jobs + $job

                # Wait for it all to complete
                Wait-Job -Job $jobs

                # Getting the information back from the jobs
                Get-Job | Receive-Job



            }
      $i++
      }while($vname[$i] -ne $null)
    }
```

Comment: How's going? Has your issue got solved ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to find all VMs with those name not containes "DB" and "web", try command below:

```
Get-AzVM | Where-Object {$_.name -notlike '*DB*' -and $_.name -notlike '*web*'}
```